# Eclipse startup problem on Fedora 12

Tags: eclipse

**The Eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its 
companion launcher jar.**
[image] 
**or**

[image]

This (above) error occurs when I am trying to start my eclipse, on Fedora 12. my jdk and eclipse both are of 32 bit.

And eclipse.ini as 

`-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.0.200.v20090520
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m`

Answer (score 1):

Has Eclipse been installed through `yum` or manually?
Is it a new install or has it been upgraded?

From the `ini` file, it looks like a version mismatch between the `--startup` jar and the `--launcher.library`.

Depending on how Eclipse was installed, you can look for existence of the specified jar and the folder.  Most likely one or both is missing or incorrect.

Comment: http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/linux-install-eclipse-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/

Comment: I solved it using a solution as a tutorials http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/linux-install-eclipse-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/          Visit it for step by step installation of eclipse on LINUX Fedora.  Thank you!